# Is it possible to get an item's current index position in a list?

Tags: c#, list, overriding

Is it possible to get an item's position in a list to do something like the following?…

```
public class ListItem
{
    public override string ToString()
    { return PositionInList.ToString(); }
}

public List < ListItem > myList = new List < ListItem >();
```

Comment: `List.FindIndex` can give you the Index, but I don't think, your element *will know its position* in the List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not saying you *should* do this, because a class knowing about its container is just odd, but you could do:

```
List<ListItem> parentList;
public ListItem(List<ListItem> parentList)
{
    this.parentList = parentList;
}

public override string ToString()
    { return parentList.IndexOf(this).ToString(); }
```

Of course, during construction you need to pass the parent collection in.

Comment: It's a good approach but unfortunately I'm not able to pass anything during construction in this case.

Comment: @Essential You could assign it via a separate property then (though there will be a period where `parentList` is null). You have to give the list to the child class *somehow*.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a connection between `ListItem` and `List`. For example you can add a property to store the list that has the `ListItem`:

```
public List<ListItem> List { get; set; }

public List <ListItem> myList = new List <ListItem>();
myList.Add(new ListItem { List = myList });
```

Then you can use `IndexOf` method:

```
public override string ToString()
{ 
    return List.IndexOf(this).ToString(); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

using the `.IndexOf()` method of the List class will allow you to do that.

```
var lst = new List<string>();
lst.Add("foo");
lst.Add("bar");

// Output the index, ie: 1
Console.WriteLine(lst.IndexOf("bar"));
```